# Find text but skip other elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I currently try to get the text out of a 'td' element but there are more elements inside it. so the find() returns me the whole text inside the td tag. Here's the Code:

```
<td class="some class">
  Some text that i want<br>
  <a href="some/link">some more text</a>       
  <span class="some other class">some more text</span>
  <br>
</td>
```

So what what i want is only the next right after the td tag. I am using BeautifulSoup.

Any suggestions how to get the text without the other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first text only you can get the 'td' class, convert it into a list and get the first index:

```
t ='''
<td class="some class">
  Some text that i want<br>
  <a href="some/link">some more text</a>       
  <span class="some other class">some more text</span>
  <br>
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(t, "html.parser")

text = list(soup.find('td'))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.text` on that element.

```
b=bs4.BeautifulSoup("""<td class="some class">
Some text that i want<br>
<a href="some/link">some more text</a>
<span class="some other class">some more text</span>
<br>
</td>""")
txt = b.find('td').text
# txt will be: u'\n  Some text that i want\nsome more text\nsome more text\n\n'
```

Comment: .text returns all text elements. So the outcome would be "some text that i want some more text some more text"

Comment: Then simply convert it `b.find('td')` to a list and use the first element as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more common way to get the "Some text that i want" would be to use `find(text=True)`, which would find the *first text node* inside a tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<td class="some class">
  Some text that i want<br>
  <a href="some/link">some more text</a>
  <span class="some other class">some more text</span>
  <br>
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
text = soup.find("td", class_="some class").find(text=True)
print(text.strip())  # prints "Some text that i want"
```

Another option would be to get the text node from the [`.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) which contains all the text node (additionally trimmed/stripped) inside a tag:

```
next(soup.find("td", class_="some class").stripped_strings)
```